# How to get the original(design) Width property of component after code changes?

Tags: delphi, width, ribbon, autosize

I put the simplest code here to show you my issue. There are two buttons, `btnTest` and `btnChangeTestWidth`.

I added **OnClick** events for both of them: 1) `btnChangeTestWidthClick` changes `btnTest` **Width** property and set value for 100 and 2) `btnTestClick` restores **Original**(Design) **Width** of button.

***The question is***: Do you know another way how to refer and get Original(Design) size of component?

In this case it is button and *Width* property. I found only this way to get original *Width* of button. The issue is I have to create variable for every button to keep this *Width* and next get it from *FromCreate* procedure. I am working on *AutoSizing of ToolBar* where I need to do it for many of them and it is not way to create variable for every of them.

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    btnTest: TButton;
    btnChangeTestWidth: TButton;
    procedure btnChangeTestWidthClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    iOrignalWidth: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm4.btnChangeTestWidthClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   btnTest.Width := 100;
end;

procedure TForm4.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   btnTest.Width := iOrignalWidth;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   iOrignalWidth := btnTest.Width;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You can use the Tag if the Width is all you need to remember

Comment: @DawidHefferman, could you please extend your comment?

Comment: @ArTi: Save the value in a variable, before it is altered. Then you can use that variable to obtain the value at any later time.

Comment: @AnreasRejbrand: It looks like the similar idea which I showed you above, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. What exactly is the problem with remembering the value.

Answer (score 1):

I know two solutions to this question:

1) Create an new dummy instance of the owner form

2) Read and parse the DFM code for the component

**Solution 1**

New VCL Applicaiton
Place a Panel and a Button on the form
Create an `OnFormCreate` event:

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Width := 100;
end;

Add an `OnClick` handler to the button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm1;
begin
  Form := TForm1.CreateNew(Application);
  try
    ReadComponentRes(Form1.ClassName, Form);
    Panel1.Width := Form.Panel1.Width;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Simple as that!

**Pros**: Simple code

**Cons**: If you fom is heavy to load it might take a while.

**Solution 2**

New VCL Applicaiton
Place a Panel and a Button on the form
Create an `OnFormCreate` event:

```
uses
  uDFMParser;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Width := 100;
end;
```

Add an `OnClick` handler to the button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rs: TResourceStream;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  DfmTree: TDfmTree;
  DfmObject: TDfmObject;
  DfmProperty: TDfmProperty;
  i: Integer;
begin
  rs := TResourceStream.Create(hinstance, TForm32.ClassName, RT_RCDATA);
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  DfmTree := TDfmTree.Create;
  try
    rs.Position := 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(rs, ms);
    ms.Position := 0;
    ObjectTextToTree(ms, DfmTree);

    DfmObject := nil;
    for i := 0 to DfmTree.OwnedObjectCount - 1 do
      if DfmTree.OwnedObject[i].ObjectName = Panel1.Name then
      begin
        DfmObject := DfmTree.OwnedObject[i];
        break;
      end;

    if DfmObject = nil then
      exit;

    DfmProperty := DfmObject.PropertyByName('Width');

    if DfmProperty = nil then
      exit;

    Panel1.Width := DfmProperty.IntegerValue;

  finally
    DfmTree.Free;
    ms.Free;
    rs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For this solution to work you need a copy of Robert Love's [DFM parser](https://code.google.com/p/robstechcorner/source/browse/trunk/Delphi/presentations/DelphiLive/DBX/Convert/uDFMParser.pas)

**Pros**: 
   Now workload from creating a dummy form
   Read and Parse DFM code

**Cons**: 
   More complex code.
   3rd party library

Both solutions are just a quick and dirty demos so you'll have to add error handling youself and make the code more generic (I've just hardcoded the component name)

Personally  I would go for Solution 2.

Comment: @arti if you want to continue with solution 2, I can help you makeing it more Generic

Comment: Thank you @JeansBorrisholt for your solutions and willingness to help. In my case I think I'll use DavidHeffernan and AnreasRejbrand suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a helper class or subclass which could be particularly helpful if you have more than one property to remember. Subclassing is the easiest to understand:

```
Unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  VCL.StdCtrls,
  System.Classes;

type
  TButton = class( VCL.StdCtrls.TButton )
  private
    fOriginalWidth: integer;
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
  public
    property OriginalWidth : integer
             read fOriginalWidth;
  end;

implementation

{ TButton }

procedure TButton.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  fOriginalWidth := Width;
end;

end.
```

Then make sure your new unit is at the end of your uses list in your main program.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Unit4;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Button1.Width = Button1.OriginalWidth then
  begin
    Button1.Width := 2 * Button1.Width;
    Button1.Caption := IntToStr( Button1.OriginalWidth );
  end
  else
  begin
    Button1.Caption := IntToStr( Button1.Width );
    Button1.Width := Button1.OriginalWidth;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Note that you can use the new extra property in the main unit even though it does not exist in the original TButton, and also you could subclass an ancestor of TButton to make it more general. 'Loaded' is called when after the form is loaded from the resources, which is why I overrode that function